# Can't add/change styles in Google Chrome Inspector

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image: google-chrome-inspector-bug]

This has been happening for a few months. I need to click anywhere in between 1 and 20 times to select or add a style in Google Chrome Inspector as seen above. I have tried disabling all extensions, incognito mode, and `restore defaults and reload` in Chrome Inspector Preferences but no luck.

Comment: https://crbug.com is the Chrome bugtracker. See if the bug was already reported, otherwise report it yourself.

Comment: I'm having the same issue while I have an ionic 2 app being served.